# Post parameters not reaching ActiveModel in Rails, unable to post data to SQLite from UI but it works from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm following along the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Martl, and for whatever reason I can't add a User to the database (sqlite3) from the UI/page. The parameters are passed without errors, and I see the parameters in the server log, yet the data doesn't reach the DB intact:

```
Started POST "/users" for 192.168.1.100 at 2013-03-05 01:20:39 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"\u2713", "authenticity_token"=>"7VZ7HobCW9YrVBf/LadINF35c9ZThTYb2vBsA+02180=", "user"=>{"name"=>"smith", "email"=>"smith@dev.com"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xa8e2934 @base=#<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:name=>["can't be blank"], :email=>["can't be blank"]}>
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 77.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

When I pass the same parameters to the DB from a Rails console, it works fine; the User gets added/saved without a problem. It's only from the UI that the data gets lost.

Here is my schema information and user model file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#



   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :email
      #has_many :microposts
      before_save { email.downcase! }

      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :email, presence: true
    end
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:id])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
      Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect) 
    end
  end
end
```

I've been staring at this code for a while now, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First and foremost**, your validations should be the first statements in your model. If you place them after the `before_save` callback then there is no use of writing them as they will get executed after the values get saved into the database.

So do the following first-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  before_save { email.downcase! }
end
```

**Second**,

Your create action should have `params[:user]` to be passed and not `params[:id]`.

Do this-

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
    Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect) 
  end
end
```

Now, run the application and check. You will see that you got the new user in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That worked. I wonder why the rails tutorial sample code has the before_save method before the validates? https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/models/user.rb